# Regex to not include white spaces

Tags: regex

Data

```
"06/12/20 ,NOVUS HOME MORTGAGE
04/22/20 ,CAP ONE NA
04/22/20 ,CAPITAL ONE
04/22/20 ,CAPITALONE
04/16/20 ,CREDCO
04/16/20 ,CREDCO
04/16/20 ,FLAGSTAR BANK OA R"
```

Regex : `"[A-Z\s]+"`

The result I wanted is  NOVUS HOME MORTGAGE,  CAP ONE NA etc all the data . but it includes space , how not to include space ? it did include the space before , I dont wanna include space

Comment: Use `[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*`

Comment: can you explain this regex Sir ?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/9M8ulq/1

Answer (score 0):

The \s will match any white space character. So removing might solve what you are asking for. (I don't fully understand your question and what you want, so just providing a suggestion)